# Using wx.html2, there are some strange points when using button tag

Tags: javascript, python, html, wxpython

```
import wx.html2
import re
import os
import cx_Oracle


class Main(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
        self.MainHtml2WebView = wx.html2.WebView.New(self, size=(0, 0), backend=wx.html2.WebViewBackendIE)

        self.MainFirstPage()

    def MainFirstPage(self):
        self.FirstPage = """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang=ko>
            <style text=text/css>   
                html, body{{height:100%;}}      
                div.up{{margin:50px auto;}}                         
                .button{{               
                    width:400px;
                    background-color:orange;
                    border:none;
                    color:#fff;
                    padding:100px;
                    text-align:center;
                    text-decoration:none;   
                    font-weight:bold;            
                    font-size:100px;
                    margin:300px auto;
                    cursor:pointer;     
                }}
            </style>
                <head>
                    <meta charset=UTF-8>    
                    <title>TITLE</title>    
                </head>                     
                <body scroll="no">
                    <div class=up>
                        <center><img src=9.png></center>                    
                    </div>                  
                    <div class=down>
                        <center><input type=button class=button value=clcik onclick="location.href='{nextpage}'"></input></center>
                    </div>  
                </body>         
            </html>         
        """
        self.Department()
        self.MainHtml2WebView.SetPage(self.FirstPage.format(nextpage=re.sub(r'\s+', " ", self.DepartmentChoie)), "")

    def Department(self):
        self.DepartmentChoie = """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang=ko>
            <style text=text/css>   
                html, body{{height:100%;}}                                                  
                .obgy{{         
                    width:500px;
                    background-color:orange;
                    border:none;
                    color:white;
                    padding:100px;
                    text-align:center;
                    text-decoration:none;   
                    font-weight:bold;            
                    font-size:50px;
                    margin:50px auto;
                    cursor:pointer;     
                    position:relative;
                }}
                .pd{{       
                    width:500px;
                    background-color:pink;
                    border:none;
                    color:white;
                    padding:100px;
                    text-align:center;
                    text-decoration:none;   
                    font-weight:bold;            
                    font-size:50px;
                    margin:50px auto;
                    cursor:pointer;     
                    position:relative;      
                }}  
                .fm{{               
                    width:500px;
                    background-color:blue;
                    border:none;
                    color:white;
                    padding:100px;
                    text-align:center;
                    text-decoration:none;   
                    font-weight:bold;            
                    font-size:50px;
                    margin:50px auto;
                    cursor:pointer;     
                    position:relative;      
                }}          
            </style>
                <head>
                <meta charset=UTF-8 />  
                    <title>TITLE2</title>   
                </head>                     
                    <body scroll=no>
                        <div>                   
                            <center>
                                <input type=button class=obgy value=TEST1 onclick="location.href='{obgypage}'">
                                <input type=button class=pd value=TEST2>            
                                <input type=button class=fm value=TEST3>
                            </center>                   
                        </div>                                      
                    </body>         
            </html> 
            """
        self.obgy()
        self.MainHtml2WebView.SetPage(self.DepartmentChoie.format(obgypage=re.sub(r'\s+', " ", self.obgychoice)), "")

    def obgy(self):
        self.obgychoice = """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang=ko>
            <style text=text/css>   
                html, body{{height:100%;}}                                                  
                .ob{{           
                    width:500px;
                    background-color:orange;
                    border:none;
                    color:white;
                    padding:100px;
                    text-align:center;
                    text-decoration:none;   
                    font-weight:bold;            
                    font-size:50px;
                    margin:50px auto;
                    cursor:pointer;     
                    position:relative;
                }}
                .gy{{       
                    width:500px;
                    background-color:pink;
                    border:none;
                    color:white;
                    padding:100px;
                    text-align:center;
                    text-decoration:none;   
                    font-weight:bold;            
                    font-size:50px;
                    margin:50px auto;
                    cursor:pointer;     
                    position:relative;      
                }}                
            </style>
                <head>
                <meta charset=UTF-8 />  
                    <title>TITLE2</title>   
                </head>                     
                    <body scroll=no>
                        <div>
                            <center>
                                <input type=button class=ob value=TEST1></input>                    
                                <input type=button class=gy value=TEST2></input>                           
                            </center>
                        </div>                                      
                    </body>         
            </html> 
            """

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    fream = Main()
    fream.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

My code is simple html like above using `wx.html2`. I'm using the `input button tag` to open the next page.

Serious here? I found something strange.

The first is that when you load the page, you can not load the page if you use a comma in all the html, and the second you have to make all the html code in one line with the regular expression.

I do not know why the comma is allowed, but this only worked `onclick = "location.href = ''"` function.

The first page can load `self.DepartmentChoie html` using `onclick = "location.href = '{nextpage}'"`

Second page `onclick = "location.href = '{obgypage}'"` can not be called. This is because the `onclick = "location.href = ''"` function has a `comma`. There is no word.

I've tried countless ways, but I could only load the first page with the `onclick = "location.href = ''"` function. Another way I would like to know how to load the `self.FirstPage -> self.DepartmentChoie -> self.obgychoice` page using the button. Other modules are also good. Other ways are also good. I really need help

Comment: What should I see if I execute the code above ?. I just get a Frame with a very small square in the center with a 'X' inside

Comment: The first page shows the orange TEST1 button.
The second page shows the TEST1, TEST2, and TEST3 button pages
The third page shows the TEST1 and TEST2 buttons.
In the above code, if you delete `onclick = "location.href = '{obgypage}'"`, the second page is linked.